# DDD: Persisting aggregates

Tags: persistence, domain-driven-design, aggregate, aggregateroot, persistence-ignorance

Let's consider the typical **Order** and **OrderItem** example. Assuming that **OrderItem** is part of the **Order** Aggregate, it an only be added via Order. So, to add a new **OrderItem** to an **Order,** we have to load the entire Aggregate via Repository, add a new item to the **Order** object and persist the entire Aggregate again.

This seems to have a lot of overhead. What if our **Order** has 10 **OrderItems**? This way, just to add a new **OrderItem**, not only do we have to read 10 **OrderItems**, but we should also re-insert all these 10 **OrderItems** again. (This is the approach that Jimmy Nillson has taken in his DDD book. Everytime he wants to persists an Aggregate, he clears all the child objects, and then re-inserts them again. This can cause other issues as the ID of the children are changed everytime because of the IDENTITY column in database.)

I know some people may suggest to apply Unit of Work pattern at the Aggregate Root so it keeps track of what has been changed and only commit those changes. But this violates Persistence Ignorance (PI) principle because persistence logic is leaking into the Domain Model.

Has anyone thought about this before?

Mosh

Comment: I know this question was answered many years ago. There is a nearly duplicate question here that's got a good answer to. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34176328/ddd-persisting-aggregate-children-only-if-changed

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have to be a problem, some ORM's support lazy lists.
e.g.
You could load the order entity and add items to the Details collection w/o actually materializing all of the other entities in that list.

I think N/Hibernate supports this.

If you are writing your own entity persistence code w/o any ORM, then you are pretty much out of luck, you would have to re-implement the same dirty tracking machinery as ORMappers give you for free.

Comment: Yes, (N)Hibernate supports adding items to lazy-loaded collections and only added items are inserted to the database.

Answer (score 1):

The entire aggregate must be loaded from database because DDD assumes that aggregate roots ensure consistency within boundaries of aggregates. For these rules to be checed, all necessary data must be loaded. If there is a requirement that an order can be worth no more then $100000 for particular customer, aggregate root (Order) must check this rule before persisting changes. This does not imply that all the exisiting items must be loaded and their value summed up. Order can maintain pre-calculated sum of existing items which is updated on adding new ones. This way checking the business rule requires only Order data to be loaded when adding new items.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure about this approach , but I think applying unit of work pattern could be the answer . Keeping in mind that any transaction should be done , in application or domain services , you could populate the unit of work class/object with the objects from the aggregate that you have changed . After that let the UoW class/object do the magic (ofcourse building a proper UoW might be hard for some cases)

Here is a description of the unit of work pattern from [here](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) :

> A Unit of Work keeps track of everything you do during a business transaction that can affect the database. When you're done, it figures out everything that needs to be done to alter the database as a result of your work.